# Drop down menu not showing with aria

Tags: javascript, dropdown, wai-aria

I have a dropdown menu that is supposed to show up when you click on the user profile name but it's not doing it for some reason. It will only show if I add "aria-expanded="true". Can someone help?

**This is in my HBS**

```
{{#if signed_in}}
  <div class="user-info dropdown" >
    <button class="dropdown_toggle" aria-haspopup="true">
      {{user_avatar class="user-avatar"}}
        {{user_name}}
      <span>
        <svg xmlns="IMAGELINK" width="12" height="12" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 12 12" class="dropdown-chevron-icon" aria-hidden="true">
          <path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" d="M3 4.5l2.6 2.6c.2.2.5.2.7 0L9 4.5"/>
        </svg>
      </span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-expanded="true">
      {{#my_profile role="menuitem"}}{{t 'profile'}}{{/my_profile}}
      {{link "requests" role="menuitem"}}
      <div class="separator" role="separator"></div>
      {{link "sign_out" role="menuitem"}}
    </div>
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

**This is my script**

```
 // Dropdowns

function Dropdown(toggle, menu) {

this.toggle = toggle;
this.menu = menu;

this.menuPlacement = {
  top: menu.classList.contains("dropdown-menu-top"),
  end: menu.classList.contains("dropdown-menu-end")
};

this.toggle.addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler.bind(this));
this.toggle.addEventListener("keydown", this.toggleKeyHandler.bind(this));
this.menu.addEventListener("keydown", this.menuKeyHandler.bind(this));
```

**This is my HTML**

```
    .dropdown-menu {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    min-width: 170px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 1000;
  }

  [dir="rtl"] .dropdown-menu {
    text-align: right;
  }

  .dropdown-menu[aria-expanded="true"] {
    display: block;
  }
```

Comment: Could we take a look at least your `this.clickHandler`, `this.toggleKeyHandler` and `this.menuKeyHandler` code please or all of the JavaScript code? If these methods set `aria-expanded` attribute of `.dropdown-menu` to `true`, then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

It’s unclear where your JavaScript comes from, but it has errors that should get fixed.

What’s happening is that the CSS code makes it so that the menu is only visible if it has the `aria-expanded="true"` attribute, via an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown-menu[aria-expanded="true"] {
    display: block;
}
```

The JavaScript then should toggle that attribute on button click. Probably there’s an error in your JavaScript that is not setting this attribute correctly.

Try to open up your browser developer tools, inspect the menu element, click on the button, and try to observe what changes.

### Errors in the current implementation

I believe it to be a great idea to base CSS on [ARIA attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA). These attributes communicate element’s meaning and status to assistive technology, that users with disabilities rely on to use web applications. Binding CSS to these attributes makes the approach ARIA-first.

But, in this case, this is a **wrong implementation of [`aria-expanded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-expanded)**.

It’s a common misconception that the attribute would be placed on the expanded element, but actually it has to go on the toggle button.

The simplest way to hide the menu then, is by means of [the `hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden).

Also, the value of `haspopup` needs to match the role of the popup, which is `menu` in this case.

```html
<button class="dropdown_toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="menu">…</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" hidden>
```

The JavaScript then will need to manage ARIA attributes on both elements, like so:

```js
clickHandler: () => {
  this.toggle.setAttribute('aria-expanded', !this.menu.toggleAttribute('hidden'));
}
```

Try to find a similar piece of code in your case.

What’s also weird is the binding to the `keydown` event, since `<button>` will automatically fire a `click` event if users activate it by means of keyboard.

Comment: Hello! So this is what' I'm showing for clickHandler in my JavaScript. 

    clickHandler: function() {

      if (this.isExpanded) {

        this.dismiss();
      } else {
        this.open();
      }
    },

Comment: Sorry @Noelle, but this does not suffice to help you further. Now the code of the `.open()` method is missing Please provide all your JavaScript code in your question.

Comment: Hello, I actually figured it out playing around with it some more. i was missing some script earlier so I added it back and it works now. THanks!